# Wowza Streaming Engine restream help required

Tags: streaming, wowza, iptv

I want re-stream this channel `rtmp://iptv.livetv.tn/live/ch2?code=ddbacc02afb09ba` through my Wowza streaming engine. I was already installed Wowza streaming engine.

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Wowza Streaming Engine Manager panel from http:// [your-wowza-server]:8088 and log in. Choose "Applications" from the top menu, then select the application that you want to use for re-streaming. This must be an application of type "Live", there's a default application named "live" that you can use, or you can create a new application.

Next, select "Stream Files" from the left menu, and click the button "Add Stream File". A pop-up window will allow you to define the stream name and source. In the upper field, write a logical name for the stream, eg. "channel2". In the lower field, write the name to the stream source (in your case: rtmp://iptv.livetv.tn/live/ch2?code=ddbacc02afb09ba). When done, click the "Add Stream" button.

Now, again select "Stream Files" from the left menu (or find and click the link "Return to Stream Files" right above the "Basic" tab). You will see the newly created stream file. Click the first icon below "Actions" - when hovering with your mouse pointer over this first icon, it'll tell you "Connect to this stream". After clicking, a window will pop-up; the only thing you have to change there, is the Mediacaster Type: choose "liverepeater" and click "OK". You will get a confirmation message.

Choose "Incoming Streams" from the left menu. It will show you the active stream and you can click the stream name to get some statistics. In the upper right corner of the screen, click the "Test Players" button to test your stream.

*NB! Make sure you always have the required legal rights and licenses to re-stream a TV channel.*

Comment: @mchellamuthu you're welcome; please mark my answer as correct and vote :)

Comment: hi bro little problem again.. i was followed ur answer but it was not working... source url was working fine vlc ... i have legal rights for re streaming this channel.. plz help me

Comment: @mchellamuthu Please don't refer to me as bro, as I'm not. In the Wowza Manager, check if the stream is listed under Incoming Streams. If not, then likely the source isn't correct. If it does but there's no picture, then check the video and audio format. You can also check the log files in the /logs folder for detailed messages.

Comment: the stream was listed under incoming streams.. but how can i check the video and audio format. there is two types of log files in log folder. 1 Access logs 2 error log..

Comment: wowzastreamingengine_access.log will have all information; you can see how the stream is pulled from the source and how it's started in Wowza.

Comment: x-file-length   x-suri  x-suri-stem     x-suri-query    cs-uri-stem     cs-uri-query
2014-10-21      09:08:47        EDT     comment server  WARN    200     -       REST API: exists(): File (/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/conf/mymodules/Application.xml) does not exists       -       -       -       81527.596       -

Comment: If I were you, I'd post a message in http://www.wowza.com/forums/forum.php. Unfortunately I don't have time to analyze the entire log file at the moment.